# What's the architecture of Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, architecture

Will Ubuntu Phone be more an Android or more a "normal" Linux? Or in other Words: will it be possible to have e.g. wxWidgets/wxWidgets-applications on it?

Comment: that really depends on the window manager, compositor, etc. they're using. There are no official comments yet as to what it will be (as far as I know) but likely something completely new or forked. But I would think that it won't be as easily customizable as your avereage linux desktop. So to put it in your words, it's probably going to be more android like.

Comment: as i think its an ubuntu interface with unity based on Cyanogenmod android rom.. thats an android custom Rom.So yes it will be android based ubuntu on phone with unity. even you know what android is based on linux , and uses linux kernels, you can run linux commands on android with terminal emulator ,and most of the commands will definitely works because its linux kernel

Comment: Yes, it is normal linux, wx widget is not supported untill it is ported to work with mir